# Add a custom word to Google Japanese keyboard

Tags: keyboard, dictionary, google-japanese-input

I am wanting to type a word in Japanese that has a unique reading (not the standard onyomi or kunyomi). As such, I'd like to add it to the Google Japanese keyboard so that I can simply type the kana, and the desired kanji will show up. At the moment I have to type out each individual kanji by their standard readings to write the desired word.

How can I add a custom reading to the Google Japanese keyboard?

For clarification, please see Tip #9 on this page for an example of how to do this in Windows:
http://nihonshock.com/2010/04/12-japanese-ime-tips/

Answer (score 0):

Gboard (Google Keyboard) has a very simple way to add new words to it.

Open the Gboard app, go to 'dictionary' > 'personal dictionary' > [Japanese] > plus (+) symbol on the top right. Now, type the desired word, and add a shortcut, that way every time you type the shortcut, it will give you the option to switch to the desired word.

For example, if I want to type the word 
`Привет` in Russian, but I don't want to switch my keyboard from English to Russian just to type that word, so I made a shortcut that every time I write the letter P the word will show up in the suggestion bar. See screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried this, but when I type the hiragana that I have listed as the "shortcut", the desired kanji doesn't show up in the list of options.

Comment: @Elessar make sure that the shortcut is added to the same language as the one that you use when typing. Try different shortcuts, otherwise I'm not sure why it's not doing it

Comment: I've tried adding the shortcut in English, Japanese, and even the "All Languages" dictionary. I've also tried restarting the phone after adding the shortcut, however, nothing seems to work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In Google Japanes Input settings, goto Dictionary tool. Click on + (plus).
Add the word, then the "Reading". Select a Category for the word you have entered (noun, first name, place, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way to add words with their readings to the Japanese keyboard.

Tap the ">" expander on the left side of the candidate word area, tap on the settings icon, then tap on "dictionary tool" and you can add words with their proper readings.

[image: Expander]

[image: Dictionary tool]